# Joining two php requests into one

Tags: php, if-statement

THank you for any help.
How do I add another condition to this same line. I have 2 requests that I need to join aka I have this

```
 if (!@$_REQUEST['urEmail']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n"; }
```

But i need to also add this to it

```
 if (!@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'])
```

I have tried

```
if (!@$_REQUEST['urEmail']) || (!@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n"; }
```

and this

```
if (!@$_REQUEST['urEmail']) && (!@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n"; }
```

But it neighter worked.
I am grateful for any help.

thank you

Comment: Verify before that you are correctly sending the request.

Comment: Don't suppress the warnings using `@`, fix the script so the error doesn't occur. Use the `empty()` function to make sure it's filled. You can combine that with `trim()` to remove spaces and if it's and email, use `filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to verify it's a valid email pattern.

Comment: The main reason neither of your attempts worked is that they both contained syntax errors that would have prevented your script from executing at all. You need to [enable error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) while developing your application so you can be informed of such things.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions both need to be inside the `if` parentheses, as such :

```
if (!@$_REQUEST['urEmail'] || !@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n"; }
```

or

```
if (!@$_REQUEST['urEmail'] && !@$_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) { $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n"; }
```

The PHP structure for an `if` construct is the following (taken from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)) :

```
if (expr)
    statement
```

And, in your case, `expr` is both of your conditions, hence you need to enclose them both in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Reiterating my comment, don't suppress the warnings using `@`, fix the script so the error doesn't occur. Use the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to make sure it's filled. You can combine that with [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove spaces and if it's and email, use [filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) to verify it's a valid email pattern.

**Example:**

```
# Check the email is set and trim it
$email = (isset($_REQUEST['urEmail']))? trim($_REQUEST['urEmail']) : false;
# Check the recaptcha is set and trim it
$recap = (isset($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']))? trim($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) : false;
# If either are empty
if(empty($email) || empty($recap)) {
    $errorsAndAlerts .= "No email entered!<br/>\n";
}
# If both filled but invalid email
elseif(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errorsAndAlerts .= "Email invalid!<br/>\n";
}
//etc...
```

At any rate, as *@Don'tPanic* mentions, make sure you have error reporting on `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, but I suspect you do since you are suppressing the errors/warnings with `@`.

One final note, to alleviate some repetition, I would maybe think about saving errors to an array and imploding them at the end:

```
# Save all errors using the push
# (mine are in a line, but yours would be throughout your script)
$error[] = "No email entered";
$error[] = "Invalid request";
$error[] = "Invalid email";
$error[] = "Poor penmanship";
# Implode with the glue when you want to output them
echo implode('!<br />'.PHP_EOL,$error).'!';
```